# C++ what is wrong with my function call

Tags: c++, visual-c++

have the following code in my main method:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Color c1(10,1,2); 
    HSL h=convertToHSL(c1);
    return 0;
}
```

With the following convertToHSL method:

```
HSL convertToHSL(Color const& c) {

   return HSL(0,0,0);
}
```

And am getting build errors in my project. Color is a class that is defined as follows:

```
Color::Color(){}
Color::Color(float r,float g,float b){
    this->r=r;
    this->g=g;
    this->b=b;
}

Color::~Color(void){}
```

HSL is defined as follows:

```
 HSL::HSL() {}
HSL::HSL(float h,float s,float l) {
    this->h=h;
    this->s=s;
    this->l=l;
}

HSL::~HSL(void){}
```

with the convertToHSL method that I already mentioned.

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Color `c1`(10,1,2); ? missing object name c1?

Comment: What are the build errors? What is `Color`?

Comment: Also, where do the build errors occur?

Comment: `HSL::~HSL(void){}` should be `HSL::~HSL(){}`. Destructors do not have parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c1` isn't declared. Did you mean

```
Color c1(10,1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Color c1(10,1,2);` ? missing object name c1